# Can't get files at root with axios.get(url) when using vscode liveServer

Tags: routes, visual-studio-code, axios

#### Description

I have a problem with vscode extension "Live Server", 
when I run the server from the index.html file which is in a folder as follows:

```
static/
    js/
    css/
    assets/
    *.json
    index.html
```

#### The problem

In the js folder I have some axios functions that are trying to get the json files. The produced requests are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1:5500/filename.json
```

But these requests fail with 404 Not Found error. Somebody knows how to configure this extension?

#### What I tried so far

Setting a custom root:

```
"liveServer.settings.root": "/static"
```

Messing with the mount option:

```
"liveServer.settings.mount": [
    ["/root", "/static"],
]
```

But admittedly, I have no idea what I'm doing here ^^

If I move the json files out of static folder (at root of project), the requests work.

```
projectRoot/
    static/
    *.json
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem comes from the extension (I may be wrong)

The option `"liveServer.settings.root": "/static"` only works when present in the main settings of VSCode. But not when added in the project settings. :/